# Const array of objects with member variable = sum of previous indexes member variable

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, constexpr, compile-time

Is it possible to create a const array of objects where one member variable is the sum of a member variable in the objects created before it?

```
class Data
{
public:
    constexpr Data(uint32_t offset, uint32_t length) :
        m_offset(offset), m_length(length)
    {
    }

    uint32_t m_offset; //would like this to be calculated at compile time
    uint32_t m_length;
};

const Data dataList[] =
{
    Data(0, 10),
    Data(10, 25),
    Data(35, 20)
};
```

offset is the sum of the length of all previous objects in the array (10 + 25 = 35 in index 2).

I'd like to avoid having to manually calculate the offset.

I've played around with `std::integral_constant` and recursive calls to `constexpr`, but nothing seems close enough to a working solution to share. Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but try it with `int` before you attempt it with structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you accept an answer based on a `std::array<Data, ...>` instead of a old C-style array, and to use C++14 instead of C++11, it's easy

The following is a full example

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

struct Data
{
   constexpr Data(uint32_t offset, uint32_t length) :
      m_offset(offset), m_length(length)
    { }

    uint32_t m_offset;
    uint32_t m_length;
};

template <uint32_t ... Ls>
constexpr std::array<Data, sizeof...(Ls)> getDataList ()
 {
   uint32_t  l0 { 0U };
   uint32_t  l1 { 0U };

   return { { (l0 = l1, l1 += Ls, Data(l0, l1))... } };
 }

int main ()
 {
   constexpr auto dl = getDataList<10U, 25U, 20U>();

   for ( auto const & d : dl )
      std::cout << " - " << d.m_offset << ", " << d.m_length << std::endl;
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP can't use `std::array` but a C++ function can't return a C-style array; a solution could be simulate a (iper-simplified) version of `std::array`, that wrap a C-style array in a trivial struct

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct myArray
 { T arr[N]; };
```

Now the full example become

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct myArray
 { T arr[N]; };

struct Data
{
   constexpr Data(uint32_t offset, uint32_t length) :
      m_offset(offset), m_length(length)
    { }

    uint32_t m_offset;
    uint32_t m_length;
};

template <uint32_t ... Ls>
constexpr myArray<Data, sizeof...(Ls)> getDataList ()
 {
   uint32_t  l0 { 0 };
   uint32_t  l1 { 0 };

   return { { (l0 = l1, l1 += Ls, Data(l0, l1))... } };
 }

int main ()
 {
   constexpr auto dl = getDataList<10U, 25U, 20U>();

   for ( auto ui = 0U ; ui < 3U ; ++ui )
      std::cout << " - " << dl.arr[ui].m_offset << ", "
         << dl.arr[ui].m_length << std::endl;
 }
```

The `std::array` simulation can be a little less iper-simplified and contain, by example, a `static constexpr` member with the dimension

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct myArray
 { static constexpr std::size_t dim { N }; T arr[dim]; };
```

so the loop in `main()` can use it

```
// ..........................vvv
for ( auto ui = 0U ; ui < dl.dim ; ++ui )
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! This is for an embedded project, and it won't compile. Is it much more complicated to use C style arrays? The error I get is on the call to getDataList for access to an uninitialized subobject(member "Data::m_offset"). It also doesn't seem to work on C++11, but does work perfectly on C++14

Comment: @cwhelms - for old C-style array a problem is that a function can't return it; so I've suggested a `std::array`: wrap a C-array and can be returned. If the problem is that you can't use `std::array`, you can simulate it in a trivial template class that wrap a C-array; if you want, I can try to modify my answer in this way; but if you need a C++11 solution... well... it's possible but not simple (I think).

Comment: I'm using IAR, which has some C++14 support, so I think I can get something to work. If you could try the template class wrapping, that would be great. Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: @cwhelm - answer improved; hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, both of these work great on my PC with gcc, just not with the IAR compiler. I keep getting an error on the call to getDataList stating: expression must have a constant value. [note]: access to uninitialized subobjct (member "Data::m_offset"). 

Since this works for most common compilers, I am still going to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @cwhelms - sorry but... I don't have an IAR compiler so... no idea what the problem with  it.